# Find out value that returns true from if statement -algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, operators, boolean-logic

Another class is going to pass in random numbers into this `method(x,y,z)`. I want to know the `boolean` that does returns true from my last `if()` statement, so I can do operations on it.  I have explained my logic in the comments.

I am still really new to this, so my logic may be wrong.

```
public static String FindDate(int x, int y, int z) {
    boolean istrue1 =(x >= 1 && x <= 31);
    boolean istrue2 =(y >= 1 && y <= 31);
    boolean istrue3 =(z >= 1 && z <= 31);
    if(istrue1 ^ istrue2){
        if(istrue1^istrue3){
            if(istrue2^istrue3){//now knowing that no values are the same, i can find the true value.
                if(istrue1||istrue2||istrue3){
                // I want to store/use/print/know which bool(istrue) that evaluated to true, so I would know if it is
                //x,y,z that went through the algorithm successfully.

                }
              }  else{return "Ambiguous";}


            }else{return "Ambiguous";}


        }else{return "Ambiguous";}
    return "true"; //I would actually end up returning the value that went through the algorithm
    }
```

Comment: return `"true"`inside your inner `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if(istrue1||istrue2||istrue3)
```

Its is easiest to just break it down into 3 differnt if statement.

```
if(istrue1)
if(istrue2)
if(istrue3)
```

No easy trick that i was hoping for. sad day.
Also the statements i did with the xor(^) operators turns out to be bad logic.

it would be easiest to this:

```
if(a&&b || a&&c || b&&c)
```

That would return ambiguous if any combo are both true.
However thats not the original question, but I thought i might as well mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You can your following: But your condition is incorrect 3 variable for two value (`true, false`) all can't be different. So your logic always return `"Ambiguous"`

```
 if(istrue1 ^ istrue2){
    if(istrue1^istrue3){
        if(istrue2^istrue3){
           //now knowing that no values are the same, i can find the true value.
           if(istrue1||istrue2||istrue3){
             // I want to store/use/print/know the bool that evaluated to true, so I would know if it is
            //x,y,z that went through the algorithm successfully.
            return "true";
      } 
 }     
return "Ambiguous";
```

Comment: OK, I see how my logic would return ambiguous. But disregarding that(Ill deal with that later). Wont the stament return "true" just return the string, not the actual book that is true? I to know the actual boolean variable that resulted in true.

Comment: So you want to know which one is true in (istrue1||istrue2||istrue3)  ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Should I break it up into 3 different if statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can store boolean values just like any other type in Java. I'm not sure exactly what your last comment means by "the value that went through", but if you want to keep track of the result of a particular test, you don't necessarily need to write something like

```
if (a == b) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

In that case,

```
return a == b;
```

is equivalent. If the expression is more complicated parens are a good idea.

```
return ((a == b) || c);
```

And instead of returning, you could always store the result and do something with it later.

```
bool test = ((a == b) || c);
action(test);
```

Comment: Storing the value is what I need. But I couldn't find action(test)? Is that in java?

Comment: `action` could be any method which accepts a boolean value.